# Can you tell if the word "Struggle" is a noun or a verb in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across this headline:

> "Class Struggle in My Family’s Hometown"

Can you tell if "Struggle" is a noun or verb without any further context?

Comment: "Struggle" is a noun here. It's modified by the noun "class" to give the noun phrase "class struggle".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132954/discussion-on-question-by-luiz-antonio-can-you-tell-if-the-word-struggle-is-a).

Answer (score 3):

Most readers should recognize the term “class struggle” from Marxist theory, and no further analysis would be necessary.

If not, however, we can quickly see that “class” as a subject and “struggle” as a verb do not agree: it should be either “class struggles” or “classes struggle”. So, ignoring the unlikely possibility that the paper’s author and/or editor made such a basic mistake, we must conclude that “struggle” is not a verb here.

Comment: I get it now. But what if I wanted to use it like: "class struggling in my family’s hometown" to visually signals "struggle" is a noun, would that be correct?

Comment: @luizantonio If you are referring to class struggle in the Marxist sense, “struggling” wouldn’t work. While ambiguous, my brain wants to read that version as a verb—the opposite of what you want.

Comment: I think I get it now: ""class struggling in my family’s hometown" can make one think there is only one class fighting for something. this ambiguity is not very  obvious for someone im process of learning English

Answer (score 0):

It is a noun. "class" and "struggle" are both nouns and we combined them to make a compound noun. For e.g. cat food or fire-fly.

Comment: I wouldn't call "class struggle" a compound noun, but a syntactic construction consisting of the noun "struggle" as head and the noun "class" as its modifier. I agree that firefly is a compound noun, but "cat food" is a syntactic construction (head + modifier).

Comment: Bro, talk in English.

Comment: If you don't understand English perhaps you shouldn't be posting answers on ELL, especially wrong ones. Note that "class struggle" is **not** a compound noun.

Comment: What is the difference between a noun phrase and a compound noun? Also, is "noun phrase" a compound noun?

Comment: wouldn't "class struggling" be clearer that "struggle" is being used as  a noun? at least visually? do "class struggle in my family’s hometown" and "class struggling in my family’s hometown" differ somehow?

Comment: @luizantonio  [*Class struggle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class%20struggle) is a standard phrase, meaning "conflict between classes", so changing it would also change the meaning.  *Class struggling* sounds like "there is one class, and it is struggling right now."

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws A compound noun is a single word consisting of two (or occasionally more) bases. A noun phrase is two or more separate words, with one noun being the main word (the head) and the other words or phrases (if present) being modifiers or complements. Compare "**greenhouse**" (compound noun) and "**green house**" (noun phrase). Note that compound nouns typically function as nominals, as in "I grow plants in my **greenhouse**".

Comment: @stangdon, theoretically if Class struggle wasn't a standard phrase could I use it like: "class struggling in my family’s hometown" to signals visually that struggle is being use as noun